# How do I sove the issue of getting the error "object 'sexe' not found"?

Tags: r, error-handling, tidyverse

I keep getting, "object 'sexe' not found", when trying to call the variable 'sexe' from my dataset.

```
names_fr <- readr::read_delim(my_url05, "\t") %>%
  filter(my_url05, sexe == 2, !is.na(preusuel), annais != "XXXX", preusuel !="_PRENOMS_RARES") %>%
  complete(preusuel, annais) %>%
  mutate(nombre = ifelse(is.na(nombre), 0, nombre), sexe = ifelse(is.na(sexe), 2, sexe)) %>%
  select(-sexe)
```

I'm still quite new to R, so the problem might lay in the way data are loading.
Im asked to load data from an url:

```
my_url05 <- "https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/eagan/class/igr204/data/nat1900-2017.tsv"
names_fr <- readr::read_delim(my_url05, "\t")
```

An object called "my_url05" is created, holding the url.
Also a spec_tbl_df are created:

`names_fr`

A tibble:

1 x 1

https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/eagan/class/igr204/data/nat1900-2017.tsv

When I load the data "manually", by downloading the dataset myself an placing it in an object, it does contain the variable called "sexe".

R is the latest version and packages are updated.

What else might be the problem?

Thank you for your help

Anders

Comment: I don't think you need `my_url05` in your first `filter` call. It's not the url that you want to filter. Leave it out, and I think it should work.

Comment: What @sparrow said works, I've just tried it. I have voted to close as off-topic/simple typo.

Comment: Thank you but nothing changed. I recieved an error again:  `names_fr <- readr::read_delim(my_url05, "\t") %>%
  filter(sexe == 2, !is.na(preusuel), 
         annais != "XXXX", preusuel !="_PRENOMS_RARES") %>% 
  complete(preusuel, annais) %>% 
  mutate(nombre = ifelse(is.na(nombre), 0, nombre), 
         sexe = ifelse(is.na(sexe), 2, sexe)) %>% 
  select(-sexe)`  : 
Error in ~sexe == 2 : object 'sexe' not found